# After training word embedding with gensim's fasttext's wrapper, how to embed new sentences?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gensim, embedding

After reading the tutorial at gensim's [docs](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/FastText_Tutorial.ipynb), I do not understand what is the correct way of generating new embeddings from a trained model. So far I have trained gensim's fast text embeddings like this:

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText as FT_gensim

model_gensim = FT_gensim(size=100)

# build the vocabulary
model_gensim.build_vocab(corpus_file=corpus_file)

# train the model
model_gensim.train(
    corpus_file=corpus_file, epochs=model_gensim.epochs,
    total_examples=model_gensim.corpus_count, total_words=model_gensim.corpus_total_words
)
```

Then, let's say I want to get the embeddings vectors associated with this sentences:

```
sentence_obama = 'Obama speaks to the media in Illinois'.lower().split()
sentence_president = 'The president greets the press in Chicago'.lower().split()
```

How can I get them with `model_gensim` that I trained previously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look up each word's vector in turn:

```
wordvecs_obama = [model_gensim[word] for word in sentence_obama]
```

For your 7-word input sentence, you'll then have a list of 7 word-vectors in `wordvecs_obama`.

All FastText models do not, as a matter of their inherent functionality, convert longer texts into single vectors. (And specifically, the model you've trained doesn't have a default way of doing that.)

There is a "classification mode" in the original Facebook FastText code that involves a different style of training, where texts are associated with known labels at training time, and all the word-vectors of the sentence are combined during training, and when the model is later asked to classify new texts. But, the `gensim` implementation of FastText does not currently support this mode, as `gensim`'s goal has been to supply unsupervised rather than supervised algorithms.

You could approximate what that FastText mode does by averaging together those word-vectors:

```
import numpy as np
meanvec_obama = np.array(wordvecs_obama).mean(axis=0)
```

Depending on your ultimate purposes, something like that might still be useful. (But, that average wouldn't be as useful for classification as if the word-vectors had originally ben trained for that goal, with known labels, in that FastText mode.)

Comment: In my case when I did: `wordvecs_obama = [loaded_model[word] for word in sentence_obama]
len(wordvecs_obama)` when I do `len(wordvecs_obama)` I get 43. What is the reason of this behavior?

Comment: With mode you refer to skipgram or cbow?

Comment: Are you sure `sentence_obama` has been `.split()` like in your shown code? (Only then would it be a list of 7 words. Otheriwise, it would be a list of 43 characters.)

Comment: CBOW and skip-gram are alternate training modes, but original FastText **also** has a 'classification mode' which works as I described, enabled by its `supervised` argument, see: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText#text-classification – but again, this `supervised` option isn't available in gensim's implementation.