# What's the equivalent to get_sentence_vector for Gensim's FastText?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word-embedding, fasttext

The official Python implementation offers the useful `get_sentence_vector()` which sums, normalizes (L2) and averages the words in the given sentence.

In other words, I'd like to embed a new sentence, given a trained model of Gensim's FastText.

Is there such method?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57082110/1453508) help?

Answer (score 2):

As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57079642/after-training-word-embedding-with-gensims-fasttexts-wrapper-how-to-embed-new/57082110#57082110), Gensim doesn't provide `get_sentence_vector` method.

You can use official fastText library or instead rewrite this method on your own ([here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/a20c0d27cd0ee88a25ea0433b7f03038cd728459/src/fasttext.cc#L490) you can find the original C++ implementation).